# Numerical solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find a numerical solution to this differential equation:

$$x''-\frac{2kqQ}{m\left(x^2+(\frac{ab}{2})^2\right)}=0$$

$k,q,Q,a,b,m$ are constants.

Can anyone recommend a program or a method for solving this? I have mathematica but I have no idea how to solve this in mathematica.

Comment: Do you have any extra conditions imposed on $x$? Initial or boundary conditions for example? You can attempt to solve that analytically (DSolve) in Mathematica, if it succeed, you'll get an answer with two extra parameters. If you want to solve it numerically you can use NDSolve in Mathematica, something of ode45 family in Matlab. Almost any computational engine is capable of doing that kind of task.

Comment: Can't you cancel one of those $\sqrt{x^2+(\frac{ab}{2})^2}$ and then you have the square root squared so that reduces to just $x^2+(\frac{ab}{2})^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes you are right. Let me fix that right away.

Comment: Also the square root is squared so that simplifies to just $m(x^2+(\frac{ab}{2})^2)$ in the denominator

Comment: do you want a numerical solution of an analytic one?

Comment: @Chinny84 I assumed there was no analytic solution. This is part of a larger physics question that I am working on. The question specifically asks for a numerical solution.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thanks. I don't know how I missed such a trivial simplification.

Comment: @Rzeta Right, now it looks a lot less intimidating.  I'd start by seeing if there's a general way to solve $x''=\frac1{x^2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mathematica* example:

```
Manipulate[Module[{sol},
  sol=First@NDSolve[{
    x''[t]-A/(x[t]^2+c^2)==0,
    x[0]==1,x'[0]==0
  },x[t],{t,0,10}];
  Plot[x[t]/.sol,{t,0,10}]],
{{A,1,"(2kqQ)/m"},0,10},
{{c,1,"ab/2"},0,10}]
```

Also, your equation is pretty solvable by hand.
Let $A = \frac{2kqQ}{m}, c = \frac{ab}{2}$. If you multiply your system with $x'$ and integrate that, you'll get the first integral of the system:
$$
x''x' - \frac{Ax'}{x^2+c^2} = 0\\
\frac{(x')^2}{2} - \int \frac{A dx}{x^2+c^2} = E\\
\frac{(x')^2}{2} - \frac{A}{c}\arctan \frac{x}{c} = E\\
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2E + \frac{2A}{c}\arctan \frac{x}{c}}} = t - t_0\\
$$

Comment: I also got to the last line..so I am going to fold and let you complete the final step ;)? I be happy to see the solution of that integral. +1 for effort though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am going to go through it tomorrow because it is really late at my place. Have a nice day

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. It turns out I set up the wrong equation of motion which led to this rather difficult diff. equation. The one I ended up having to solve was much easier and I was able to solve it in mathematica. Thank you very much for your help though.

Comment: Same question as  Chinny84. +1 too.

Answer (score 0):

*Just another way (leading to the same result as @uranix.*

To make notations simpler, let
$$\alpha=\frac{2kqQ}{m}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=\frac{a b}{2}$$ making the equation to be
$$x''-\frac{\alpha}{x^2+\beta^2}=0$$ Switching variables
$$\frac{t''}{[t']^3}+\frac{\alpha}{x^2+\beta^2}=0$$ Reduction of order $p=t'$ gives
$$p=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\beta }}{\sqrt{2 \alpha  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\beta }\right)+ c_1}}$$ No way to go further even if $c_1=0$.